# Anah contradictions in Genesis

Tags: exegesis, genesis, kjv

First I am going to post these 3 verses from Genesis (King James Bible):

Genesis 36:2 :

> Esau took his wives of the daughters of Canaan; Adah the daughter of Elon the Hittite, and Aholibamah the daughter of Anah the daughter of Zibeon the Hivite;

Genesis 36:24 :

> And these are the children of Zibeon; both Ajah, and Anah: this was that Anah that found the mules in the wilderness, as **he** fed the asses of Zibeon his father.

Genesis 36:20 :

> These are the sons of Seir the Horite, who inhabited the land; Lotan, and Shobal, and Zibeon, and Anah

So I have two questions regarding these verses:

1- Is Anah a he or she? In the first verse Anah is referred to as the daughter of Zibeon and in the second verse Anah is referred as a he.

2- Is Zibeon the father of Anah? In the first two verses it is mentioned that he is the father but in the last verse it seems that they are brothers!

Comment: You might want to consider how [other Bible translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Genesis%2036:2) read in verse 2. Many translations clarify that verse by using punctuation or phrasing in order to make it clear that Anah isn't the one who is the daughter. Anah is male.

Answer (score 1):

Its really not that difficult. At that time in Israel she would have been considered the daughter of both he genetic father and **his** genetic father. It was common practice to list the names of genetic fatherhood for several generations. There are many instances of that in the Old Testament. In the book of Ruth you will find her listed as the daughter of Mordaci; even  though he was actually her uncle.

Since Anah was a common name listing the genealogy of the individual was a way of describing the particular individual. That is the reason for the listing of Zibeon as Anah's father in 36:24; and Sier as the father in 36:20. Quite simply they are two different individuals.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you clarify who your pronouns refer to? Who is "she" in the second sentence?

Comment: @4castle the her in that sentence refers to Aholibamah  referred to in Genesis 36:2 in the question.